# Firebase Database structure UID

Tags: firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am asking myself if this kind of database structure is good, because of identifying the user with an PK **AND** putting the UID again under that PK. I dont know if that makes really sence or even more, could be dangerous?

```html
{
  "Users" : {
    "7idb6ThWR8aqmnEHFao5GRCV1kI3" : {
      "dPicture" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/parkir-ngasal.appspot.com/o/Profile_images%2Fcropped1465266876.jpg?alt=media&token=44f83fdf-935a-4b3c-8138-561dcba2fca7",
      "status" : "hi my name is erik",
      "uid" : "7idb6ThWR8aqmnEHFao5GRCV1kI3",
      "username" : "erik"
    }
  },
  "posts" : {
    "-KfsrGsY8TWb2wiMFtAq" : {
      "dPicture" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/parkir-ngasal.appspot.com/o/Profile_images%2Fcropped1465266876.jpg?alt=media&token=44f83fdf-935a-4b3c-8138-561dcba2fca7",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/parkir-ngasal.appspot.com/o/Post_Images%2Fcropped1354055061.jpg?alt=media&token=77fbc9ed-4356-43c1-b7bb-9563300a8b7b",
      "small_title" : "tes",
      "summary" : "tes",
      "title" : "tes",
      "uid" : "7idb6ThWR8aqmnEHFao5GRCV1kI3",
      "username" : "erik"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not dangerous. The security you set at the parent level traverses downward. From the Firebase docs:

> .read and .write rules work from top-down, with shallower rules
>   overriding deeper rules. If a rule grants read or write permissions at
>   a particular path, then it also grants access to all child nodes under
>   it.

As to if it makes sense...that's up to you decide. While there's nothing wrong with duplicating the key inside the data structure, it's not needed. It's just as easy to retrieve the data from the key as it is from the payload.

```
 const data = await firebase.database().ref(`/Users/`).once('value');

 const users = _.map(data.val(), (val, key) => {
   return { 
     userId: key, 
     val.username, 
     val.dPicture, 
     val.status
   };
 });
```